# white page shown only in IE8/IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a strange problem... I am developing a web app to search house rentals , and the website is showing great in FF, Chrome, but in IE i get a white page....
Could you please hint what's up with the code? Maybe some java-script problem?
I have digged out , but I am stucked.

Comment: sorry, the link is http://rentforme.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is :

```
</head>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<div style='border: 1px solid #F7941D; background: #FEEFDA; text-align: center;   clear: both; height: 75px; position: relative;'>
<div style='position: absolute; right: 3px; top: 3px; font-family: courier new; font-weight: bold;'&gt;&lt;a href='#' onclick='javascript:this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none"; return false;'&gt;&lt;img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-cornerx.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Close this notice'/></a></div>
<div style='width: 640px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; padding: 0; overflow:   hidden; color: black;'>-->;
</head>
```

You have 2 close tag for head, and between you have a big empty div. That's what is displayed on IE.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going through these HTML errors as a first stage to debugging!: [http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3a%2f%2frentforme.net%2f](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://rentforme.net/).  There are 81 errors listed there.  From a quick look, it appears the `<HEAD>` and `<BODY>` start/end tags are overlapping.